# Stuck converting binary to integers in python

Tags: python

hi i have this code by which my output comes in binary.

```
b=np.array(np.zeros((1000,4)))

for i in range(1000):
    n = "{0:04b}".format(int(Y[i]))
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(n)]
    b[i] = digits
```

this gives an output like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
please ignore the commas.. read it like [0 0 0 1]---binary number.
```

im trying to change it such that it gives integers like:

```
1
```

can anyone help me with this.. how to edit my code to bring out integers rather than binary numbers.?

Comment: 0 is an integer

Comment: no! dont bother the commas...its actually [0 0 0 1] which is a binary number converted to integers gives us 1.
read it in binary format you will understand

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in `int()` will do this for you:

```
binary_num = ''.join(arr)
regular_num = int(binary_num, 2)  # 2 is the base
```

Comment: where exactly should i change? and add this?

Comment: Convert your list to a string using the first line, then convert that string to an int using the second.